# Dimension, basis of a subspace of R$^{5}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V =$ **R**$^{5}$ and $U = \{(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5) ∈$ **R**$^{5}$$
 | a_1 - 2a_3 = 0$}.

I've shown that $U$ is a subspace of **R**$^{5}$. I believe I found a basis but I just want to make sure. The basis would necessarily have 5 vectors, right? And hence the dimension of $U$ would be 5? I know this would be true if $U$ = **R**$^{5}$ but I'm unsure if it's true when $U$ is just a subspace of **R**$^{5}$.

Comment: $U$ has five dimensions to live in. But there is one constraint $a_1-2a_3=0.$ So, it has dimension four.

Comment: okay. So if we had a constraint, say, $a_1 - a_2 +a_3 = 0$ then we would conclude it has dimension 3? Or isn't this still a hyperplane, and hence has dimension 4?

Comment: If both constraints are linearly independent then the dimension of the subspace is three. This is the case of your example. But if you had the linear constraint  $2a_1-4a_3=0$ then the dimension is 4. Note that both constraints are the same. This is clear with two constraints but it's more difficult to see with more constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A subspace does not have to have the same dimension as the space it's from. In fact, $U$ actually has 4 basis vectors, since there is a linear relation between $a_{1}$ and $a_{3}$. To see why this would be true, think about **R**$^3$. This would be a subspace of **R**$^5$, which would be trivial to show, and we already know it has a dimension of 3.

Answer (score 1):

Since $a_1- 2a_3= 0$, $a_1= 2a-3$.  So we can write $(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5)= (2a_3, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5)$$= (0, a_2, 0, 0, 0)+ (2a_3, 0, a_3, 0, 0)+ (0, 0, 0, a_4, 0)+ (0, 0, 0, 0, a_5)$$= a_1(0, 1, 0, 0, 0)+ a_3(2, 0, 1, 0, 0)+ a_4(0, 0, 0, 1, 0)+ a_5(0, 0, 0, 0, 1)$.

That should make it obvious that {(0, 1, 0, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, 1)} is a basis for this subspace and that its dimension is 4.